# 3D scatter on GUI axes

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot

I've a problem with doing `scatter3` in my gui `axes`, that the `scatter3` function do not support passing the axes handle as a parameter.

---

Function syntax from Mathworks documentation [ There is nothing about axes handle ]

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C)
scatter3(X,Y,Z)
scatter3(X,Y,Z,S)
scatter3(...,markertype)
scatter3(...,'filled')
scatter3(...,'PropertyName',propertyvalue)
h = scatter3(...)
```

---

Assume that axes handle is `hAxes`.
and here is a sample data from function documentation:

```
[x,y,z] = sphere(16);
X = [x(:)*.5 x(:)*.75 x(:)];
Y = [y(:)*.5 y(:)*.75 y(:)];
Z = [z(:)*.5 z(:)*.75 z(:)];
S = repmat([1 .75 .5]*10,numel(x),1);
C = repmat([1 2 3],numel(x),1);
```

**Q1:** *How Can I do the 3D scatter plot on the axes with handle `hAxes` ?*

**Q2:** What I've figure out is the problem happens with only one axes, the scatter plot appear in 2D as if it's a normal `scatter`.

What the problem could be ?

Comment: I'm sorry for such question ! it was naive, I should have investigated more before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

Although it's not mentioned but it seems like axes handle can be passed normally, that this cab be trivially done by the following code:

```
scatter3(hAxes, X(:),Y(:),Z(:),S(:),C(:),'filled');
```

**Answer2:**

It's 3D but It need a rotation tool to get the view from different angles !

Comment: You can adjust the view angle with the [`view`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) command.